# How to pass data to controller action from view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net application.

I have an image displayed inside the view of a controller action. When I click on an item in the view (say an image) I would like to pass some data (say ID) to a controller action.

I have the following code in the view:

```
@Url.Content("ActionName", "Controller");
```

I would like to send the data into the ActionName action of the Controller controller.

And the controller action looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string someParam)
{
   return View();
}
```

I can call the controller action without a problem but I cannot pass the data. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new {id = "ID"})'>
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/MyLinkImage.png")' />
</a>
```

Comment: I did, I was just waiting for the cool down time period on accepting answers on SO

Answer (score 1):

You can Add image in URL action or create onclick function for image and make Ajax request

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {someParam = "value"})">
       <img />
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make an ajax call

an example below

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button
    var element = this;    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
                $(element).closest("form").submit(); //<------------ submit form
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Emil, can this be done without using an ajax call? I'm looking at different images that are displayed on the page and when any of the image is clicked, the entire content related with the image is displayed on a separate page.

Comment: you can just have the url on the click pointing to the Action with a parameter  @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {someParam= "someParam"}). But this will reload the whole page

Comment: Thanks @Emil for the answer. However, the answer provided by shajeer seems to work fine and is less complicated.